# Set properties from java.util.Properties object to mule flow property placeholders at runtime

Tags: spring, properties, mule

I have been successful in loading the mule app properties from the database at app init and setting them to the property placeholders of mule flows. The code for this is referenced here [Read mule props from the DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38054331/read-properties-from-database-and-use-it-instead-of-mule-app-properties/38073859#38073859)

However, this works only during app startup. I want to be able to modify the properties in the database(which I can) and make it reflect on the mule flows at runtime without restarting the mule server.

To acheive this, I created a new flow with a Http Listener which invokes a java class that reads the properties from the database and tries to set it to bean factory using the PropertySourcesPlaceHolderConfigurer class. The sample code of the java class looks like this.

```
@Autowired
ConfigurableListableBeanFactory configurableListableBeanFactory;

@Autowired
MyService myService;

public MuleEventContext onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext){
Properties properties = new Properties();

    // get properties from the database
    Map<String,String> propertiesMap = getMuleAppPropertiesFromDB();
    if(null != propertiesMap && !CollectionUtilsIntg.isEmpty(propertiesMap))
        properties.putAll(propertiesMap);

PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer cfg = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
cfg.setProperties(properties);
cfg.postProcessBeanFactory(configurableListableBeanFactory);
}
```

This code ran succesfully but failed to set the properties to the mule app flows at runtime.

Does anyone have any idea how else this can be achieved?

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe PropertyPlaceholders life is ends as soon as application starts fully i.e. they are limited to application init and during beans creation only. If you want to be able to change properties at runtime, then you should not use property placeholders but use other properties mechanisms like creating a bean of `org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule  xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd">

    <http:listener-config doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" port="8081"/>
    <spring:beans>
        <spring:bean id="myProps" name="myProps" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
            <spring:property name="properties">
                <bean factory-bean="databasePropertiesProvider" factory-method="getProperties" />       
            </spring:property>
        </spring:bean>
    </spring:beans>
    <flow name="test">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" doc:name="Recieve HTTP request" path="/test"/>
        <logger message="#[app.registry.myProps['testPropertyName']]" />
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Instead of reading from file, you can use to load from db. Then in your mule config use these as #[app.registry.myPropes['mykey']]. Read about MEL context objects [here](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/mule-expression-language-basic-syntax#context-objects-variables-and-fields).

In sample code above, I registered `myPoros` bean and loaded properties from database. `app.registry` is application registry context object available in mule, it gives you access to spring beans.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @manik-magar. How should I use the PropertiesFactoryBean to set the properties loaded from database? I have a java.util.Properties object as I have shown in the question above. And what is app.registry? Do I have to set the Properties object to the registry? If so, then How? Please help!!

Comment: I updated answer to show sample code. Remember, this cannot be 100% replacement for Properties configurer, especially for properties that defines beans. For example, host in http listener or path in file inbound endpoint. Those properties are read at bean creation and changes to source will not be reflect unless your restart app (that is why your changes were working for start of the app only.).

Comment: Thanks for the reply and a pretty good explanation @manik-magar !!!. I will try this out and see If it works for me. I'll update how it goes.
Regards!!

Comment: I am able to reload the properties from the database at runtime. Thanks for your inputs @Manik-Magar. Really helped me solve my problem. Appreciate you help.
Regards!!